# July 2016 Community Challenge

Tags: discussion, fun, community-challenge

We've just gotten the [June 2016 Community Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6740/june-2016-community-challenge) going, so it's time to pick one for July.

---

It's time to choose a [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge) for July 2016.

- Post your challenge as an answer to this question. Feel free to resubmit non-winning ideas from previous months.
- Vote for those answers which interest you.
- At the end-of-day on Thursday, June 30th, the top-voted post will become the next challenge.

Once the challenge topic is decided, post your solution as a [question on the main site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and tag it with [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge). The challenge runs throughout July (but nothing stops you from posting an entry later on).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Monopoly

A [Monopoly question was posted recently](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/129763/27623), and was very well received by the entire Stack Exchange community.

So my proposal is to [***create a Monopoly game***](http://richard_wilding.tripod.com/monorules.htm). It seems like it'd be a challenge to implement this game well, but easy enough to get a lot of participants involved.  And, as always, bonus points for AI players.

Comment: It's a board game spree!

Comment: I'm actually really excited about this idea - this will be fun to make happen.

Comment: For those doing the Monopoly challenge, check out [this](http://www.jdawiseman.com/papers/trivia/monopoly-rents.html) and [this](http://www.math.yorku.ca/~zabrocki/math2042/Monopoly/prices.html) for values / board orientation.

Comment: AI as in rule based AI, or self learning AI. Or does that refer to my brain being augmented with a wifi dongle and 5TB hard drive?

Comment: Actually I might give this one to my son (12) to try on Scratch.

Comment: @Gareth You can make any kind of AI that you want, whether it's just playing randomly or using state-of-the-art Machine Learning technologies.

Comment: Were there no submissions on this challenge?

Answer (score 6):

## Create an [IoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things) application

Maybe you've been looking for an excuse to finally dust off your [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). Maybe you have an [Amazon Echo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Echo) and you want test out some of its functions, or maybe you just want to finally finish your [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) project or just write a smartwatch app!

Either way, this is for you and anyone else who may have interest in the hardware side of things / include images/videos where applicable, bonus points for communication on multiple layers / integration across several platforms.

Comment: I really like this idea, but not having any of those thing (I don't own a Raspberry Pi, Amazon Echo, Arduino or a smartwatch) I find it hard to rally here. Is there some ideas that anybody could work on ?

Comment: Well, it doesn't necessarily have to use any of those - your computer / phone for communication is fine, however, it is fundamentally a hardware project so something external is inherently necessary. I can make a list of potential projects if people need reference, but I find they can be surprisingly simple, inexpensive and actually useful...an example could be attaching rotors to window blinds so they can be altered remotely.

Comment: Simply the fun of working on something smaller than your usual computer can be worth the 30 bucks a Raspberry costs nowadays. They got HDMI, just plug them into your TV or monitor and SSH into them.

Comment: I really like this idea! However, I don't know if I could use my RPi again because, last time I used it, I shorted a 5v (or 3.3v) pin directly to a GND pin :)

Comment: I actually have an Amazon Echo (been sitting in the box since I moved in February), I need to get it back out and do this with it anyway.

Comment: I actually took a look a while ago at implementing a trivia game for the echo, hm

Answer (score 5):

## Cover a board with dominoes

Given an arbitrarily sized and shaped board of squares, find

1. If there is a way to cover it with dominoes (2x1 squares) such that each square is covered and no two squares overlap.
2. If there is a way to cover it, the number of different ways it can be covered.

Bonus:

1. For each domino covering in 2 above, draw/write the covering.
2. Generate a board with a specified number of domino coverings. Even more bonus: draw/write all the coverings.

Input would be passed as an `array` of `chars` (or a `string`, whatever your program can read from a file passed via `stdin`) where a square is represented by `'■'` and an empty space is represented by `' '`. The input for bonus two would be an `int` (or long, if you wanted to allow for very many coverings).

The output should be at least the number of coverings, with 0 being valid to mean there are no coverings. Bonus 1 could vary depending on your language/library. You could use a graphics toolkit to actually draw the board and dominoes, or make some form of ASCII representation of it and write it to a file or `stdout`. Bonus 2 would work the same; either draw it or write it.

Example input file 1:

```
■■
```

Output: 1

Example input file 2:

```
 ■
■■■
```

Output: 0

Example input file 3:

```
■■■■
■■■■
```

Output: 5

Example input file 4:

```
  ■
■■■
 ■
 ■
 ■■■
   ■
```

Output: 1

Example input file 5:

```
■■■■
■■■■
■■■■
```

Output: 10